# Tcl: write lambda and map using tcl 8.6

Tags: tcl

How do I write and apply a simple lambda function using the tcl 8.6 features "apply" and "lmap"?

```
map (lambda x -> x*x) [list 1 2 3]
```

how can I write the above in Tcl 8.6? The man pages are not that self explanatory for me.

Perhaps also a more advance version, but I guess I can figure that out myself:

```
lambda y -> map (lambda x -> x*x) y
```

Basically I would like to improve this version:

```
proc \x {f val} {
    set res [apply $f $val]
    set res
}

set res [\x {x {expr $x*$x}} 5]
puts "res: $res"
```

So that I can just write:

```
set res [\x {expr $x*$x} 5]
puts "res: $res"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what `lambda` looks like:

```
proc lambda {arguments expression} {
    list ::apply [list $arguments [list expr $expression]]
}
```

Then we do this, noting that `{*}` is required because the inner lambda term can't be a command directly without causing other trouble that we didn't want to have in 8.5 (or 8.6):

```
set res [lmap x [list 1 2 3] {
    {*}[lambda x {$x * $x}] $x
}]
```

The 8.6 `lmap` is syntactically like `foreach`, so an extra layer of application is needed. It is, however, more easily understood by average Tcl programmers for being like that.

Note that the lambdas are *fully* first-class values that can be passed around however you want (put in variables, returned, stored in a list, whatever):

```
set square [lambda x {$x * $x}]

puts "the square of 42 is [{*}$square 42]"
```

(You could use `λ` for a command name if you wanted, but I find it awkward to type on this keyboard. I don't recommend using `\x` though; Tcl uses backslashes for various escaping duties.)